# Test connection and output in GUI screen in Powershell

Tags: powershell

With the below code, my goal is to ping a hostname and have it return if successful or unsuccessful, and project that on the GUI screen itself. At the moment I am getting errors on the "-TargetName".

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

# Create window form 
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text = 'Device Info'
$main_form.Width = 600
$main_form.Height = 400
$main_form.AutoSize = $true

# Start of code
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = "Hostname"
$Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 30)
$Label.AutoSize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($Label)

# Adding textbox
$TextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(90, 30)
$TextBox.Width = 300
$main_form.Controls.Add($TextBox)

# Adding check button
$CheckButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CheckButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 30)
$CheckButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120, 23)
$CheckButton.Text = "Check"
$main_form.Controls.Add($CheckButton)

# Perform event when check button is clicked
$ComputerName = $TextBox.Text 

$CheckButton.Add_Click(
    {
        Test-Connection -TargetName $ComputerName -IPv4
    }
)

# Show Window
$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grab the value from `$TextBox.Text` *when the button is clicked*, and then use the correct parameter name (`-ComputerName` rather than `-TargetName`)!

Change this:

```
$ComputerName = $TextBox.Text 

$CheckButton.Add_Click(
    {
        Test-Connection -TargetName $ComputerName -IPv4
    }
)
```

To:

```
$CheckButton.Add_Click(
    {
        $ComputerName = $TextBox.Text 
        Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -IPv4
    }
)
```

Comment: "Test-Connection : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TargetName'. "


Still getting the same error.

Comment: @gameandscripts I completely missed that, the correct parameter name is `ComputerName` :)

Comment: Thanks for that :) I got an error with the -IPV4 but once removed, no errors and it looks like its proceeding to the next step.

I know I need an If statement now to project onto the GUI "Success/Not Pingable" but where would I place this line of code? After the "ShowForm" or before?

Comment: @gameandscripts No, also inside the button Click handler - otherwise it won't run neverytime you click the button :)

Comment: To take a step back, how do I know if the test connection is even working? I'm not getting any errors but am also not getting anything on the powershell interface.

Comment: @gameandscripts I just assumed you'd want to inspect the output from `Test-Connection` inside the click handler and then update some other UI element on your form with the results :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248103/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-gameandscripts).